# Почему <li> не растягивается по высоте дочернего элемента <a>?

Tags: html, css

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">asdw</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">asd</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">qwe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">werqs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Почему `li` не растягивается по ширине и высоте от размеров вложенной ссылки, то есть размеры блока `li` остаются равными высоте текста, но `padding` не учитывается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип дисплея в цсс надо сменить. например на флекс.

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
li {
        display: flex;

}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a  href="#">asdw</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">asd</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">qwe</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">asdf</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">werqs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">asdw</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">asd</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">qwe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">werqs</a></li>
</ul>
```